# How to map mysql point type in java using mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

How to map mysql point type in java using mybatis? It is java.lang.Object now.
This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location` point DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And this is the xml that the generator gives:

```
  <resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="package.model.Test">
    <id column="id" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="id" />
    <result column="location" jdbcType="OTHER" property="location" />
  </resultMap>
  <insert id="insert" parameterType="package.model.Test">
    insert into test (id, location)
    values (#{id,jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{location,jdbcType=OTHER})
  </insert>
```

I have tried:

```
public void testPointType() {
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
    com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(1, 1));
    package.model.Test record = new package.model.Test();
    record.setLocation(point.toText());
    testMapper.insertSelective(record);
}
```

But get: `com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what fields is in model `Test` and not sure if it works for you, but just try it;)

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="package.model.Test">
    insert into test (id, location)
    values (#{id,jdbcType=INTEGER}, Point( #{location.x}, #{location.x} ))
</insert>
```

And I think you'd better define you model `Test` like:

```
public class Test {
    private String id;
    private String locationX;
    private String locationY;

    ... ...
    getter and setter
    ... ...

}
```

And then you can do it like this:

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="package.model.Test">
    insert into test (id, location)
    values (#{id,jdbcType=INTEGER}, Point( #{locationX}, #{locationY} ))
</insert>
```

For this kind model `Test`, you can do `select` like:

```
<select id="insert" resultType="package.model.Test">
    select id, x(location) as locationX, y(location) as locationY from test
</select>
```

Comment: and how to select ?

Comment: @Tiina Updated answer, check it please.

Comment: That is one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

After hours digging. I was looking for this way:

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="package.model.Test">
    insert into test (id, location)
    values (#{id,jdbcType=INTEGER}, GeomFromText(#{location,jdbcType=OTHER}))
</insert>
```

and in java, the model could have point type as Object, and assigned with a String "point(1 1)" or using vividsolutions `geometryObject.toText()` method.

It didn't work at beginning was because, without `GeomFromText()`, mybatis sees it as `insert int test (id, location) values (1, 'point(1 1)')`, there is a quotation around the value.
to select:

```
<select resultType="java.lang.String">
    select astext(location) from test
</select>
```